# BroadCastReceiver Not calling on BOOT_UP

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-service

i want to run BackGround service on boot up. so i created broadcast receiver and in on receive i called that background service as below.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("BroadCast Receiver", "In OnReceive Method");
         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context , BackGroundService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent); 
    }

}
```

i regestered receiver in manifest file and given the boot_up permission.

```
<receiver
          android:name=".BootReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action
              android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
            </action>
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

my background service class

```
public class BackGroundService extends IntentService {

public BackGroundService() {
        super("BackGroundService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = ((ConnectivityManager) BackGroundService.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
                          if (cm == null)
                              return;
                          if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                                             System.out.println("internet Availble");
                            //  t.cancel();


                          }else{
                              System.out.println("internet Not Availble");
                                     }
}
 }, 0, 60000*3);
}
}
```

The log which is in onReceive is not showing in logcat.Which means onReceive is not calling on BootUp. is there any thing wrong in my code. can any one help me on this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Still not able to find the problem. i am running this on 4.0.3.

Comment: @LalitPoptani,Still not able to find the problem. i am working on 4.0.3 micromax tab.